# Jquery UI Autocomplete: search from multiple attributes of one array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hi I'm trying to get the jQuery UI autocomplete widget to work so that it searches for matches from **multiple** attributes of my array (not just one that it does by default).

I've messed around with their example, however I'm still unsure how to solve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/FUZPN/

Here's my array format in `script`

```
var projects = [
    {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        other: "9834275 9847598023 753425828975340 82974598823"
    },
    {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        other: "98 83475 9358 949078 8 40287089754 345 2345"
    },
    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        other: "49857 2389442 573489057 89024375 928037890"
    }
```

What I'm seeking is that if you type "write", the first element should pop up in autocomplete, similarly if you type "jq" the first 2 elements should pop up.

---

According to the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

> Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
>
> - An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`
>
> The **label** property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The **value** will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only **value** properties, the **value** will also be used as the **label**.

How do I (hard)code it so the source uses **2 labels** (`label` and `desc`?) instead of the one **label**?

---

*(Sorry I've searched for many similar questions, however they all aim at multiple sources, which is not here since I only have 1 array .. is it?)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Autocomplete  accepts a [third type of source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), a function, that can provide data any way you see fit:

> The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can
>   be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets
>   two arguments:
>
> - A request object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters
>     "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
> - A response callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the
>     provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for
>     simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source
>     callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the
>     response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that
>     the widget always has the correct state.

This means that you can write something like this

```
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        // request.term is what you typed
        console.log(request.term); 

        //call response with an array containing the filtered data
        response([...]); 
    }
});
```

A simple solution to your problem:

```
function lightwell(request, response) {
    function hasMatch(s) {
        return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase())!==-1;
    }
    var i, l, obj, matches = [];

    if (request.term==="") {
        response([]);
        return;
    }

    for  (i = 0, l = projects.length; i<l; i++) {
        obj = projects[i];
        if (hasMatch(obj.label) || hasMatch(obj.desc)) {
            matches.push(obj);
        }
    }
    response(matches);
}

$( "#project").autocomplete({
    source: lightwell
});
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FUZPN/5/

Comment: For those who may need a bit more explanation, a similar, and highly commented, answer based off the above great answer is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44587413/1063287