# jQuery UI Autocomplete Search by multiple fields

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI autocomplete and it is working fine. Below is the sample code:

```
<element>.autocomplete({source: availableTags,
position: {
    my: "left top",
    at: "left bottom",
    collision: "flip"
}});

})
```

and

```
availableTags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
```

Can I add Multiple fields here? Like tags associated with value? For e.g, "java" has associated tag called "language".

How can i setup source in a way that if user search for "java" or they search "language", both should return "java"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI Autocomplete: search from multiple attributes of one array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846710/jquery-ui-autocomplete-search-from-multiple-attributes-of-one-array)

Comment: This does not appear to be a complete example. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve